# Can I send data to Bigquery using local Json file?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to send data from local JSON file stored on my PC. I also want to use "WRITE_APPEND" option to append new data to existing one. How can I do that using Java libraries? Previously I used insertAll() method to stream all of the data at once to the BigQuery but I want to use the other way to do it with "WRITE_APPEND" option.

I tried to work with LoadJobConfiguration but I was getting error "Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location: output.json". I wanted to use local JSON file.

Comment: Can you also use `Python` sdk instead of Java ? It simpler to load Json and Dict to `BigQuery`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The entire project is based on java.